# Conflict between masonryjs and mustachejs

Tags: javascript, mustache, jquery-masonry

I have a syntax error somewhere in my javascript that seems to be slipping by. I can either access the content through a file into a mustache template, or I can hard code the items (images and audio) and have the items smoothly fill up the page with masonryjs. But when I try to add both, either or both will not work. Here is my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/JdEZXb/)

What I expect to happen is to have my page generated from the document feeding my mustache template. But it should stack smoothly like sites like Pinterest where the images tile neatly since I used masonryjs.

Here is the code that works with Masonry

### HTML

```
<div id="content" class="container clearfix">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/img/1.JPG" alt="" />
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/audio/1.wav">
    </audio>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/img/2.JPG" alt="" />
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/audio/2.wav">
    </audio>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/img/3.JPG" alt="" />
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/audio/3.wav">
    </audio>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/img/4.JPG" alt="" />
    <audio controls>
      <source src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/audio/4.wav">
    </audio>
  </div>
<!-- The rest of the items handcoded -->
</div> <!--/ #container -->
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Initialize Masonry
  $('#content').masonry({
    columnWidth: 320,
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
      $(this).masonry('reload');
    });

});
```

But When I add mustache so that it is not hand coded, then it fails. I tried doing this

### HTML

```
<div id="content" class="container clearfix">
  <div id="image-list"></div>


  <script id="imgtpl" type="text/template">
    {{#images}}
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/img/{{img}}" alt="{{alt}}">
        <audio controls>
          <source src="http://assets.wtfisthat.info/audio/{{id}}.wav">
        </audio>
      </div>
    {{/images}}
  </script>
</div> <!--/ #container -->
```

### JS

```
// Streams in the data from the JSON file
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/101702/img.js',   function(data) {
    var template = $('#imgtpl').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('#image-list').html(html);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Initialize Masonry
  $('#content').masonry({
    columnWidth: 320,
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
    $(this).masonry('reload');
  });

});
```

Comment: What is the problem? Define: Input, expected output, observed output, error information (exceptions)

Comment: @Amit I added more details. Basically I can either use mustache or masonry but not both. If I could use both my page would be generated and the images would tile neatly. But I seem to have an error in how I am structuring my script.

Comment: Your codepen results in the following error: `TypeError: $(...).masonry(...).imagesLoaded is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwJXpW

I've changed your code so that the new elements are appended to the existing ones, instead of pushing them inside their own div.

Then, you should use `masonry('appended', $elements)` once the elements are added, as explained in this page: [adding items](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/adding-items.html).

Here is the modified script:

```
$.getJSON('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/101702/img.js', function(data) {
    var template = $('#imgtpl').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    var $html = $(html)
    $('#content').append($html).masonry( 'appended', $html); 
  });
```

Comment: This works in the demo but for some reason not on the live site